# How can I create a Tinder-like card stack swiper in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a card swiper and I tried out a few packages already, but none of them were decent and customizable enough, so I considered creating something on my own.

What approach should I go with to create animations, draggable card and a stack of cards, (a new card should be added to the bottom on every swipe)?

Comment: No idea how this got upvoted, This is too broad and not what stack-overflow is for

Answer (score 1):

This is a rough idea, but it might work.

I would suggest creating a `CardComponent` and have them stack on each other, with the last one at the bottom.

```
return (
   <div className="card-container">
       {
            this.state.cards.map((card, index)=>{
                 return (<CardComponent key={card.id} details={card}></CardComponent>)
            })
       }
   </div>

)
```

Something like that.

Then in the CSS part, set `.card-container` to be a holder, and then use the order of the elements of `CardComponent` which would return `<div>stuff here</div>`.

Then set `.CardComponent > div` to position things absolute and then take advantage of the `z-index` property.

Use this code for whenever you want to remove the first card and append a new card to the end (at the bottom of the card stack).

```js
var count = 0;
// Reverse the array, so you can order from bottom to front
$('.card-container > div').reverse().each(
    function() {
        $(this).css('z-index', ++count);
    }
);
```

Then you can update the cards state.

```
let newCardList = this.state.slice(1);
let newCard = null; // Add the new card here
newCardList.append(newCard);
this.setState({
    ...this.state,
     cards: newCardList
})
```

So on the swipe event on said CardComponent, just get the key from the event, play a slide animation using jQuery, and after the animation ends, just slice the cards array like in the above code.

Also you will need to call this, after you slice, and add a new card.

`$('.card-container > div').reverse().each(`

Answer (score 0):

You can do these kind of stuff with : https://github.com/react-voodoo/react-voodoo

Here a demo example of tinder like mini app with it : https://codesandbox.io/s/tinder-like-card-swiper-1735w

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33355293)

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming you work on a web browser app mainly for computer users.

- for animations you can just decompose the move in a couple frames,
- for the swipe you can go with custom event functions if you can't find anything existing,
- the stack of card is a simple state management and I recommend using hooks.